# what exactly undoStopAfter and undoStopBefore options in edit method mean how do they behave

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

[image: edit method on TextEditor of Vs Code Api]

```js
e.edit((editBuilder) =>{//here e is an object of texteditor 
            editBuilder.insert(_p, content);
            return true;
        },
        {undoStopAfter : true ,undoStopBefore : false}
    ).then(x=>{
       // what will happen after specifying undoStopAfter and undoStopBefore options?
            return true;
        });
```

Comment: Running into problems with the undo behaving strangely when working on an extension. Would love to know the answer to this too!

Comment: As of today they seem to do nothing for `insert`, which might be related to https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/38535. I wonder if the `replace` undo behavior still works for https://stackoverflow.com/a/57725180/257568.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They specify if an "undo stop" should be inserted before and after the document change (in this case an edit) is executed. An "undo stop" is like a checkpoint you access when using ctrl+z/ctr+y. If both are set to `false`, then the edit will practically be part of the previous edit in the otherwise inaccessible history stack that vscode uses.

See [my question and answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71787897/7829241) for an example of a use-case.

By default it seems like `edit` adds an "undo stop" before and edit (`undoStopAfter : true`), but it is ambiguous if it adds one after an edit.